# Getting the sum of a column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

trying to get the sum of (total) column in "transactions" table where the type="outbound" but i cant get it to print out.

```
$stmt4 = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT SUM(total) FROM transactions WHERE proid=$id ");
$stmt4->execute();
$thetotal= $stmt4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $thetotal;
```

I'm getting this error

> Array to string conversion in (..)

How do I echo the sum of total column?

Comment: `echo $thetotal['SUM(total)']` also works without using a alias in SQL, but @Qirel 's answer is more generally used.  And also mind the SQL injections as `$id` is still prone there which Qirel also mentioned.

Comment: just to add... the `echo` command cannot print arrays. For debugging, if you want to see the data in any variable (including arrays), you can use `print_r` instead: `print_r($thetotal);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you fetch the result-set, you get an array of results - this can't be printed as a value from `echo`. You need to select which exact column you want to print. That is easier if you assign it an alias, by doing `SUM(total) AS tot` - now the name of the sum is `tot`.

Also use proper bounded parameters with your prepared statement.

```php
$stmt4 = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT SUM(total) as tot FROM transactions WHERE proid=?");
$stmt4->execute([$id]);
$thetotal = $stmt4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $thetotal['tot'];
```

Comment: You can also fetch numeric indexed array and access the zero'th element. There are many ways to Rome.. ;-)

Comment: I agree. I posted alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning** Never put PHP variables in SQL string. It makes your SQL vulnerable to SQL injections and can be the cause for a lot of problems for you.

You can solve your problem by using [`fetchColumn`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

```
$stmt4 = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT SUM(total) FROM transactions WHERE proid=? ");
$stmt4->execute([$id]);
$thetotal = $stmt4->fetchColumn();

echo $thetotal;
```

or you can use `fetch` with `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN`

```
$stmt4 = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT SUM(total) FROM transactions WHERE proid=? ");
$stmt4->execute([$id]);
$thetotal = $stmt4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

echo $thetotal;
```

Comment: whats a better way if i shouldn't use variables in my sql?

Comment: Use prepare and execute as demonstrated in my answer. You should put only placeholders in query then pass the data through execute function.